# Why does this regex unit test fail?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I'm writing an app using Dart / Flutter.

I've written this regex function to check certain strings:

```
  static final String nameOnCardRegex = r'^[\-A-Z `’\.\' '`]';
  static final int nameOnCardMaxLength = 21;

  static bool checkNameOnCard(String nameOnCardInput) {
    if (nameOnCardInput == null ||
        nameOnCardInput.length > nameOnCardMaxLength) {
      return false;
    }
    return RegExp(nameOnCardRegex).hasMatch(nameOnCardInput);
  }
```

I'm trying to unit test it with this function:

```
  test("[Name On Card String Validator] Check invalid Name On Card input 2",
          () async {
        expect(YouStrings.checkNameOnCard("TEST @NAME"), false);
      });
```

I expect this function to return false (because i'm passing in a `@` character).
It however returns true.

Test results:

```
package:test_api                                   expect
test/data/string_validator_module_test.dart 151:9  checkNameOnCardTest.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                         _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError
test/data/string_validator_module_test.dart        checkNameOnCardTest.<fn>

Expected: <false>
  Actual: <true>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the regex101: https://regex101.com/r/AmJ0Rv/1

Your regex matches the `T` in `TEST @NAME`, so that means the issue isn't with the code but with your regex, if the expected answer isn't `true`

Try using this:

```
^[-A-Z `’.\' '`]+
```

and checking if the result is the same as the original string.

Alternatively, you can use this regex:

```
[^-A-Z `’.\' '`]
```

If there is a match, then you should return `false` and if there isn't you should return `true`. What this regex does is check if there is any characters that aren't allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the link and info. That is very helpful. Your suggested regex still matches true when i don't expect it to though. I'm expecting it to return false when there is any character in the string that isn't in the regex.

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans I know. You have to get the string match of it and see if it is the same string as the input string.

Comment: Really? Is there no way to return just true or false using regex without doing that?

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans Well, actually I'll update my answer in a second

Comment: Thanks! I removed them

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I've removed them from my answer as well